# Binding value from XML file in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to bind a value from a XML file I'm getting online to my XAML-code do display the value in the app.

My application is pretty simple.

I use XDocument to read the xml-file with currency rates. I want to select the USD_Sell value that looks like this in the xml online.

```
<row>
  <swift_code>USD</swift_code>
  <swift_name>american Dollar</swift_name>
  <multiply>1</multiply>
  <buy_cash>8,5199</buy_cash>
  <buy_tc>8,2643</buy_tc>
  <sell_cash>9,3801</sell_cash>
  <sell_tc>9,4739</sell_tc>
</row>
```

Then my main method only looks like this so far.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace CurrencyConverter
{
public partial class CurrencyConverterPage : ContentPage
{
    public CurrencyConverterPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("http://www.forex.se/ratesxml.asp? id=492");

    }

  }
}
```

While my XAML looks like this.

```
<Label  Text="USD Sell" 
       TextColor="Black"
       Font="Medium"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

<Label  Text="{Binding USDSell}" 
       TextColor="Black"
       Font="Medium"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

Comment: Try reading directly into a DataTable : DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.ReadXml("http://www.forex.se/ratesxml.asp? id=492")

Comment: Can you evolve your comment please? I'm new to reading xml-files online

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't copy the entire URL.  It should be the entire URL.  Reading into a DataTable will make it easy to bind than to bind to an XDocument.

Comment: Why would I copy the entire URL into a datatable if I only need the value for USDSell? Cant I just put that into a variable?

Comment: You have to download the entire file.  You are current putting results into an XDocument and then need to parse the XDocument to get the USDSell value.  I'm just proposing to do the equivalent in one step using ReadXml and have the data in a format that is easy to bind to XAML code.

Comment: Aaah I see, I understand your way of thinking. But the link is the XML file and it gets downloaded once you do the XDocument? And then you load into table to be able you use the table to retrieve the results after for the binding?

Comment: You could read the file using XDocument.Load() Then use a XmlReader to Read into the DataTable, but the DataTable.ReadXml() does everything in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your XML to bind to C# classes, I used

http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

to get

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "row")]
public class Row
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "swift_code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sell_cash")]
    public string SellCash { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sell_tc")]
    public string SellTc { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "web_dis_rates")]
public class WebRates
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "row")]
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

You can now use HttpClient and StreamReader to deserialize that back to the object:

```
async Task<Row> GetRow()
{
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WebRates));

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(await client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.forex.se/ratesxml.asp?id=492")))
        {
            WebRates root = (WebRates)xs.Deserialize(reader);
            return root.Rows.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == "USD");
        }
    }
}
```

You can now set your ItemsSource to GetRows and bind in XAML to your Row properties.

Comment: Dont really understand your answer. Is it necessary to parse the xml? We're already reading it into the xml into XDocument. The only thing I need to access is the USD_Sell value.

Comment: @SterlinkArcher I edit'd it down to only include sell_cash and sell_tc, there is no value for USD_Sell. Do you mean where the element name is USD and you want the sell_cash or sell_tc? But yes, you do need to parse it to an object or you can't bind to it. You could use a data table, but why would you? This is much more explicit and easier to understand what's going on, and if you ever need to add more properties it's just adding it to the xml again.

Answer (score 0):

Linking to a response in the Xamarin forums: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/248361#Comment_248361

```
var document = XDocument.Load("http://www.forex.se/ratesxml.asp? id=492");
var row = document.Descendants("row").FirstOrDefault();
if(row != null)
{
    var sellCash = row.Element("sell_cash")?.Value;
    USDSellLabel.Text = sellCash;
}
```

Use `Descendants` and `Elements` to find the proper value of the node you're looking for.