# How to navigate Xamarin Form, After click on notification

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to navigate Xamarin Form after click on notification.(Means Get back the app)
How to do?

```
using Plugin.LocalNotifications;

void OnScheduleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var notification = new NotificationRequest
    {
        NotificationId = 100,
        Title = "Meeting",
        Description = "Your meeting is after one hour.",
        ReturningData = "Dummy data",
        Schedule =
        {
            NotifyTime = GlobalVar.ReservDate.AddHours(-1) 
        }
    };
    NotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I tested this plugin and when I clicked the notification, it will get back to the forms page. What happened when you clicked it?

Comment: Yes default it's back to home page , but i want to navigate page after click. @
Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: Want to navigate some specific page. @ Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: Please check the update part in my answer, and I can hit the tapped event now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, please add the notification tapped event according to the [official document](https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification#receive-local-notification-tap-event).

And then in the app.cs, if you use the code  `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());` , you can try to navigate to other page by the following code:

```
 private void OnLocalNotificationTapped(NotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
    }
```

If you use the code `MainPage = new MainPage()`, you can try the following code:

```
private void OnLocalNotificationTapped(NotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new Page1();
    }
```

**Update**

Please add the code into the mainactivity, such as

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        NotificationCenter.CreateNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannelRequest());
        LoadApplication(new App());
        NotificationCenter.NotifyNotificationTapped(Intent);
    }

protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    NotificationCenter.NotifyNotificationTapped(intent);
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
}
```

And in you app.cs:

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NotificationCenter.Current.NotificationTapped += OnLocalNotificationTapped;
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
   
    private void OnLocalNotificationTapped(NotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
    }
```

Comment: Can you look my xmlrpc class.
 Currently the values are retrieving from array numbers. But I would like to retrieve the values from Key name. [link](https://github.com/AdityaRaj2025/ZZAPP/blob/main/XmlRpc.cs) @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Can you post a new question and show the detail code? I don't know the key of the code in the link you provide.@Raj

Comment: I can't understand the `Currently the values are retrieving from array numbers. But I would like to retrieve the values from Key name`.  Which line? @Raj

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in XMLRPC. I'm trying to understand how this working.  @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: But I have never used the xmlrpc. @Raj

Comment: Same, Ok First I'm trying to understand how this  work. @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: I'm trying to set WebView in auto size inside grid. But auto is not working. Please look this code [link](https://github.com/AdityaRaj2025/ZZAPP/blob/main/Demo.cs)  @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: What does the `not working` mean? You can post a new question and show the effect you want.@Raj

Comment: Please look this [new queston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73148534/im-trying-to-set-webview-in-auto-size-inside-grid-in-xamarin)  @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Can you post a picture to show the effect you get and the effect you want?@Raj

Comment: Do you mean the webview's height can fit its content? @Raj

Comment: Yes. @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246843/discussion-between-liyun-zhang-msft-and-raj).

Comment: Please look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73440218/after-updating-android-11-to-12-my-splash-screen-is-not-showing-my-app-icon-ar) @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: That is an existed issue on the [github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6517). Goolge uses another library show the splash screen and the xamarin  does't integrate it. @Raj

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, the library has been integrated in the xamarin at 8/6/2022. The package named `Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.SplashScreen`, and I tried to use it but failed. @Raj

Comment: Thank you for this new update, I will also try this package. @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Yes, `Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.SplashScreen` is not working. @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: The point is I can't find any document about this package. Maybe we need to wait someone used it successfully to show the way how to use it. @Raj

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will do this later. Thanks! @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: How to get data from the local xml file and bind to xaml.? Please look this [ViewModel](https://github.com/AdityaRaj2025/ZZAPP/blob/main/RoomListViewModel.cs) @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: What's the type of the data in the xml? In addition, the code in your viewmodel doesn't work? @Raj

Comment: Yes now this not working. [XML](https://github.com/AdityaRaj2025/ZZAPP/blob/main/Room.xml) plz look this @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Did you insert the data into the xml by yourself? @Raj

Comment: Yes.. @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837914/binding-value-from-xml-file-in-xamarin-forms). @Raj

Comment: This is my vb code same  I would like to do using c# in xamarin [VB](https://github.com/AdityaRaj2025/ZZAPP/blob/main/RoomLoad.vb)  @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: You can try to post a new question and I never used these api. So maybe I can't provide effected ideas. @Raj

Comment: why this line raised Exception FileNotFound  `reader = new XmlTextReader(new FileStream(Path.Combine("Room.xml"), FileMode.Open));`  @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Where does the xml file locate? @Raj

Comment: root of the project @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Please check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#embedding-in-shared-projects). @Raj

Comment: Please look my new post here i 'm trying [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73482799/how-to-get-data-from-local-xml-file-and-binded-with-xaml-xamarin) @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247541/discussion-between-liyun-zhang-msft-and-raj).