# My WebView shows a lot of unused area as shown in the image. Xamarin c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have implemented a custom web view renderer in Droid project.
The issue is, in my WebView showing lot's of unused space. Please see image.

[image]

XAML Part

```
<ContentPage.Content>
       
        <StackLayout >
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout >
                        <Label Text="Be Happy" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        <Label Text="This article is about the online encyclopedia." TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        <Button Text="Test" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"  />
                        <Label Text="Test" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        <Label Text="This article is about the online encyclopedia." TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        <Button Text="Wikipedia" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"  />
                        <Label Text="Test" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        <Label Text="This article is about the online encyclopedia." TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        <Button Text="Wikipedia" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"  />
                        <Label Text="Test" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        <Label Text="This article is about the online encyclopedia." TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        <Button Text="Test" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"  />
                    </StackLayout>
                                     
                    <StackLayout x:Name="stackview"  BackgroundColor="Red"  />

               </StackLayout>              
            </ScrollView>                              
        </StackLayout>
      
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Codebehind Part

```
public partial class WebViewTest : ContentPage
 {
        
        string url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia";
        public WebViewTest( )
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var browser = new MyWebView
            {
                Source = url,
            };
          
            if (url == "")
            {
                browser.IsVisible = false;             
            }
            else
            {
               
                stackview.Children.Add(browser);
            }

        }
}
```

For Custom renderer, I'm following this code [Custom renderer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73148534/im-trying-to-set-webview-in-auto-size-inside-grid-in-xamarin/73150233#73150233:%7E:text=%5Bassembly%3A%20Xamarin,SetWebViewClient(new%20ExtendedWebViewClient())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%7D%0A%20%7D%0A%20%7D:%7E:text=AppTest.Droid%0A%20%7B-,public%20class%20MyWebViewRenderer%20%3A%20WebViewRenderer,-%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20public%20MyWebViewRenderer)

Comment: If you are talking about the empty space below the content, I assume that webview has no idea how much space will be taken by the HTML of a page, so takes whatever space is available. If you "know" what size you want, you could set a `HeightRequest`. What do you want to put in the space below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the webview to fix the blank space in your layout. You can just get the height of the space and set it as the webview's `HeightRequest`.

Such as:

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    { 
        browser.HeightRequest = (belowcontrol.Y - abovecontrol.Y);
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```