# How to get data from local XML file and binded with XAML. Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working on Xamarin.Android and trying to get data from local XML file and bind with XAML.

Problem is `throw Exception("There is no store file.");` is coming.
Please help me to figure out how to fix this **exception** and what needs to be done to bind the XML data with the XAML.

Store.xml file is located in the Root of the project.

*Any help is appreciated. Thanks!*

I used the following code:

ViewModel-

```
public static void StoreLoad()
        {
            Dictionary<int, StoreData> newlist = new Dictionary<int, StoreData>();
            XmlTextReader reader;

            try
            {
                reader = new XmlTextReader(new FileStream(Path.Combine("store.xml"), FileMode.Open));
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("There is no store file.");
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to load store file.");
            }

            try
            {
                reader.Read();
                reader.MoveToContent();
                if (reader.LocalName != "StoreList")
                    throw new Exception("Store file is corrupt.");

                reader.Read();
                reader.MoveToContent();
                while (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    if (reader.LocalName == "Store")
                    {
                        int code;
                        string name;
                        string number;
                        int dept = 0;

                        code = int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("Code"));
                        number = reader.GetAttribute("Number");
                        name = reader.GetAttribute("ShortName");

                        string deptStr = reader.GetAttribute("Dept");
                        if (deptStr != null && deptStr.Length > 0)
                            dept = int.Parse(deptStr);
                        else
                            // If App is not supported, set fixed at 0.
                            dept = 0;

                        newlist.Add(code, new StoreData(code, number, name, dept));
                    }
                    reader.Read();
                    reader.MoveToContent();
                }

                StoreData = newlist;
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Model:

```
public class StoreData
    {  
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int Dept { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You need full path of the xml file if it is not in same folder and the c# executable.

Comment: It's on same folder. @jdweng

Comment: The path may be wrong or you do not have permission to open the file.  Xml is text so I would try to open file with notepad and see if you can read the file.

Comment: What is the build action for the file?

Comment: Why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73616712/if-the-date-is-today-and-the-time-is-1400-i-want-to-display-the-next-remaining ?

Comment: I will update question with my code later. Thank you @Enigmativity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, please set the file's build action as the EmbeddedResource. And then you can try the following code to read the content from the file.

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(Your class name)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectNameSpace.Room.xml");
```

For more information, please check the official document about [Embedding in Shared Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#embedding-in-shared-projects) and there is an sample about binding the data in the xml to the controls in the xaml.

In addition, you can try put the file in the Assets folder and then get it's data with the dependency service.